# Get created Component with a MousePressEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I created a component composed by a Text and a Rectangle.

I put it in an AnchorPane at some Specific Position.

And I would like select it with a click.
I use a MousePressEvent but with:

- GetSource(), I get the AnchorPane
- GetTarget(), I get the text or the rectangle

What should I use to get my component?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just find out the soluce...

In fact, it is really dumb, you just have to get the parent of the target you have clicked on (you probably need to convert your shape).